# (Android) FLAG_SECURE does not work when return before moving page

Tags: android, flutter

I would like to set FLAG_SECURE for the entire application and prohibit screenshots.
My MainActivity looks like this.

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE) // it
    }
}
```

At the start of application, FLAG_SECURE works correctly and screenshots cannot be taken.
But, when Navigator.push is used to move to another page and then the back button is used to return to before moving page, the screenshot is acquired.
FLAG_SECURE is not working.

Is anyone else experiencing the same thing?
Or does anyone have a solution?

For reference, I will describe my environment and device.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale ja-JP)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
```

My device: `Huawei Honor10 COL-L29 Android 10`

Thanks.

Something else I tried was screen_protector, but it didn't solve the problem!
https://pub.dev/packages/screen_protector

I would expect that the back button would not take a screenshot if you go back to the page you were on before you navigated to it

Comment: Could be an Android bug. You should test it on more devices with more recent OS and security updates.

Comment: thanks comment. I tried it on Android 13 and FLAG_SECURE works as expected!